# Cypher constraint on direction of successive relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher, path-finding

**short version:** I need to get a path that can contain different relationships in different directions. However, I have a constraint on my path where if it contains successive relationships of a particular type, then both relationship must be in the same direction.

**long version**: 
I am using the query below to get a path between two nodes:

`MATCH p=shortestPath((n:Class { code: '1' })-[r*]-(m:Class { code: '4'})) WHERE NONE(x IN NODES(p) WHERE 'Ontology' in labels(x))  return p`

The query correctly returns me a shortest path between the two nodes. However I need to further constraint this query so that it returns only path where successive relationship of a particular type are in the same direction.

For example, suppose the relationship `-a->` need to be in the same direction, it should not return `(1)-a->(2)<-a-(3)-b->(4)` but can return `(1)-a->(6)-a->(3)-b->(7)<-c-(5)<-d-(6)-e->(4)` or `(3)-b->(7)<-c-(4)` .

The above examples were just a simplification of my real data. In my real use case, I need to find a shortest path between a node with IRI 
`http://elite.polito.it/ontologies/dogont.owl#Actuator` and another node with IRI `http://elite.polito.it/ontologies/dogont.owl#StateValue`. The query below is a specific query that encodes the path I need and it returns a path, that is the path exist. I need to make it more generic using shortestpath.

`MATCH p=(n:Class {iri: 'http://elite.polito.it/ontologies/dogont.owl#Actuator'})-->(a:Class)<--(b:ObjectProperty{iri:'http://elite.polito.it/ontologies/dogont.owl#hasState'})-->(c:Class{iri:'http://elite.polito.it/ontologies/dogont.owl#State'})<--(d:Class{iri:'http://elite.polito.it/ontologies/dogont.owl#hasStateValue'})-->(e:Class{iri:'http://elite.polito.it/ontologies/dogont.owl#StateValue'}) return p`

**Is this possible with cypher ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should work if you want to capture paths that are consistent in either direction (but it has to invoke `shortestPath()` twice):

```
MATCH (n:Class {code: '1'}), (m:Class {iri: '4'})
OPTIONAL MATCH p1=shortestPath((n)-[*]->(m))
WHERE NONE(x IN NODES(p1) WHERE 'Ontology' in labels(x))
OPTIONAL MATCH p2=shortestPath((n)<-[*]-(m))
WHERE NONE(y IN NODES(p2) WHERE 'Ontology' in labels(y))
RETURN p1, p2
```

`p1` and/or `p2` will be `null` if there is no consistently rightward or leftward path, respectively.

However, if you know that you want a specific direction (say, rightward), then this should work:

```
MATCH p=shortestPath((:Class {code: '1'})-[*]->(:Class {iri: '4'}))
WHERE NONE(x IN NODES(p) WHERE 'Ontology' in labels(x))
RETURN p
```

Comment: no, this will not work,i've added some more examples in my question, basically intermediary relationships can be in any direction

Comment: OK, I think I understand what you are now saying, but I believe your modified example result does not match your query.

Comment: in the modified result, it is not obligatory to have `-a->`, but if ever there is more than one in succession, they have to be in the same direction

Comment: What I meant was: your query is looking for `1` at one end and `4` at the other,  but your modified example can have `7` instead of `4`.

Comment: No, the query doesn't work, i've added another example with a specific query that work